# not able to find the right formatting for Elsevier double column style

Tags: two-column, elsarticle, dtx

I want to use a double column format for Elsevier like [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0890695503003262), which basically should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LagXJ.png). However I'm not able to find the right template or figure out the right settings. From their official [LaTeX instructions](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions) I have downloaded [this elsarticle folder](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle.zip). where there are some files:

- `elsarticle.dtx`
- `elsarticle.cls`
- some other `.tex`, `.pdf`and `.sty` ... files

They have also provided a "[documentation](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/pdf_file/0008/56843/elsdoc-1.pdf)" which IMHO is very messy and confusing. I would appreciate if you could help me know:

1. Where I can find a proper template similar to the [sample paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0890695503003262) I mentioned earlier
2. If there are no templates how I can get the double column formatting using those `.dtx`, `.cls` or `.sty` ... files

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Can you provide an MWE? Your questions seem to be too general.

Comment: @SinaAhmadi what is MWE? I have provided an example paper which I want to use plus the journal I want to publish in.

Comment: @Foad: [MWE = minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Regarding your problem, you might also want to have a look at page 13 of the documentation: '`twocolumn`: should be used along with `3p` option...'. Thus, maybe using `\documentclass[twocolumn, 3p]{elsarticle}` results in the desired layout.

Comment: @leandriis thanks for the explanations. [this is the journal](https://www.elsevier.com/journals/international-journal-of-machine-tools-and-manufacture/0890-6955/guide-for-authors) I want to publish in. How do I find out if it is `3p` or `1p` or `5p`? is there any template which I can use?

Comment: Page 11 of the user guide -- which you've chosen to summarily dismiss as "very messy and confusing" -- of the `elsarticle` document class states what the document class options `1p`, `3p`, `5p`, and `twocolumn` do and, in particular, which combinations of the four options do what. The links to the two screenshots you provided don't furnish nearly enough information to let anyone judge which options may be the ones *you* need to use.

Comment: dear @Mico thanks for you comment. the first place I started is the [official guidelines for the authors](https://www.elsevier.com/journals/international-journal-of-machine-tools-and-manufacture/0890-6955/guide-for-authors). What I expected to find is a template which I can use as a start point. and there are no mentions of which class option should I use. that's why the whole thing is very confusing to me.

Comment: The user guide of the `elsarticle` document class should be available on most systems by typing `texdoc elsarticle` at a command prompt. If you get a browser window with several options, be sure to choose `elsdoc.pdf`. The "Guide for Authors" webpage is decidedly not the user guide for the `elsarticle` document class.

Comment: @Mico thanks for the `texdoc elsarticle`. I did not know that. But I had already seen the `elsdoc.pdf` which I referred to as messy in the OP :) at this moment I do not know what `\documentclass` options should I include to get a similar style as [the paper](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0890695503003262/1-s2.0-S0890695503003262-main.pdf?_tid=0d95ba9b-82ee-496a-aac9-5d4f63aa5a52&acdnat=1541162051_eed00b6e6ff3bafffa4a1b6cfe30ed24) I have mentioned in the OP.

Comment: The manual says that all article class options apply to elsevier class, so use `\documentclass[twocolumn]{elsevier}`.  (Yes, they should have at least mentioned them by name.)